# Python: How to find mode (1st col - object), grouped by 2nd col, output into 3rd col

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, pandas

I'm using Python 2.7 (in iPython Notebook) and I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Client': [161252, 8858, 8858, 8858, 8858, 56552, 56552], 
               'State': ['NE', 'MN', 'MN', 'TX', 'MN', 'NJ', 'WA']})
```

What I would like to do is group the rows by "Client", find the mode of "State" for each client, then put the output into a new column called "Mode_State".  The "State" column is a Python object.

I've tried the following:

```
from scipy.stats import mode
df.insert(1, 'Mode_State', ' ')

df['Mode_State'] = df['State'].groupby(df["Client"]).transform(mode)
df
```

This results in the following:

```
    Client  Mode_State  State
0   161252  NE           NE
1   8858    MN           MN
2   8858    3            MN
3   8858    MN           TX
4   8858    3            MN
5   56552   [NJ]         NJ
6   56552   [1]          WA
```

I realise that scipy.stats also includes the number of the mode, so I tried 
the following (just to return the two character State information, not the 
mode number):

```
df['Mode_State'] = df['State'].groupby(df["Client"]).transform(mode[0])
df
```

Which of course gave me:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-1050c2b46d90> in <module>()
      1 from scipy.stats import mode
      2 
----> 3 df['Mode_State'] =     df['State'].groupby(df["Client"]).transform(mode[0])
      4 df

TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I have also tried the various responses on StackExchange that deal with strings (e.g. lambda, agg, map etc). and am getting variations of my first result or error messages.  If there are two equal modes (e.g. Client 56552 has NJ & WA) it is ok for the result to be returned as the lowest.

I'd be grateful if someone has some tips to point me in the right direction.

Thanks (note, am obviously still learning Python so am not very experienced. Have been working my way through Wes McKinney's Python for Data Analysis but
the working with strings is proving a bit more challenging for me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Mode_State'] = df.groupby('Client').State.transform(lambda group: group.mode())


>>> df
   Client State Mode_State
0  161252    NE         NE
1    8858    MN         MN
2    8858    MN         MN
3    8858    TX         MN
4    8858    MN         MN
5   56552    NJ         NJ
6   56552    WA         WA
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander, this worked well for me.  Just one question, client 56552 has equal modes (NJ & WA), so is there a way to have the answer populate as the lowest (i.e. NJ & NJ)?

Comment: Per the doc string for df.mode: `Gets the mode(s) of each element along the axis selected. Empty if nothing
has 2+ occurrences. Adds a row for each mode per label, fills in gaps
with nan.

Note that there could be multiple values returned for the selected
axis (when more than one item share the maximum frequency), which is the
reason why a dataframe is returned. If you want to impute missing values
with the mode in a dataframe ``df``, you can just do this:
``df.fillna(df.mode().iloc[0])``
`

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Mode_State'] =df['State'].groupby(df["Client"]).transform(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for responding - this returns the counts for me (i.e. as a number, so 8858 has 4 as a response in each row of Mode_State), not the most common state (e.g. MN).

Comment: this works. However Alexander's proposal uses the built-in function (faster probably). My solution may be more flexible in some cases. In particular, I think value counts sorts tied values by lexicographic order, so there is some predictability in terms of which one will come first.

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll keep this in mind for future use & appreciate your clarification.

Comment: well if you like you can always vote up my answer :)